# How to count number of words in delimited string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count, split, csv

For example i have the table called 'Table1'. and column called 'country'.
I want to count the value of word in string.below is my data for column 'country':

```
country:
"japan singapore japan chinese chinese chinese"
```

expected output: in above data we can see the japan appear two time, singapore once and chinese 3 times.i want to count value of word where japan is count as one, singapore as one and chinese as one. hence the ouput will be 3. please help me

```
ValueOfWord: 3
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing multiple values in a single column. If you properly normalize your model, this is a very easy query.

Comment: Did you store that string in a single entry???

Comment: yes. it is in single entry i want to count the value of every word in a single entry string

Comment: Split the delimited string into rows, and then count the distinct. See [**Split single comma delimited string into rows in Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is a bad design to store multiple values in a single column as delimited string. You should consider **normalizing** the data as a permanent solution.

With the denormalized data, you could do it in a single SQL using **REGEXP_SUBSTR**:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(regexp_substr(country, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL))) as "COUNT"
FROM table_name
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(country, ' ')+1 
/
```

**Demo:**

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS
  2    ( SELECT 'japan singapore japan chinese chinese chinese' str FROM dual
  3    )
  4  -- end of sample_data mocking real table
  5  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(regexp_substr(str, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL))) as "COUNT"
  6  FROM sample_data
  7    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, ' ')+1
  8  /

     COUNT
----------
         3
```

See [**Split single comma delimited string into rows in Oracle**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/) to understand how the query works.

---

**UPDATE**

For multiple delimited string rows you need to take care of the number of rows formed by the **CONNECT BY** clause.

See [**Split comma delimited strings in a table in Oracle**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/) for more ways of doing the same task.

**Setup**

Let's say you have a table with 3 rows like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(country VARCHAR2(200));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('japan singapore japan chinese chinese chinese');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('singapore indian malaysia');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('french french french');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

COUNTRY
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
japan singapore japan chinese chinese chinese
singapore indian malaysia
french french french
```

- Using **REGEXP_SUBSTR** and **REGEXP_COUNT**:

We expect the output as `6` since there are 6 unique strings.

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(regexp_substr(t.country, '[^ ]+', 1, lines.column_value))) count
  2    FROM t,
  3      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
  4      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
  5              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.country, ' ')+1
  6      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
  7    ORDER BY lines.column_value
  8  /

     COUNT
----------
         6
```

There are many other methods to achieve the desired output. Let's see how:

- Using **XMLTABLE**

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(country)) COUNT
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT trim(COLUMN_VALUE) country
  4    FROM t,
  5      xmltable(('"'
  6      || REPLACE(country, ' ', '","')
  7      || '"'))
  8    )
  9  /

     COUNT
----------
         6
```

- Using **MODEL** clause

```
SQL> WITH
  2       model_param AS
  3       (
  4        SELECT country AS orig_str ,
  5               ' '
  6               || country
  7               || ' '                                 AS mod_str ,
  8               1                                      AS start_pos ,
  9              Length(country)                           AS end_pos ,
 10              (LENGTH(country) -
 11              LENGTH(REPLACE(country, ' '))) + 1        AS element_count ,
 12              0                                      AS element_no ,
 13              ROWNUM                                 AS rn
 14        FROM   t )
 15        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Substr(mod_str, start_pos, end_pos-start_pos))) count
 16        FROM (
 17              SELECT *
 18              FROM   model_param
 19              MODEL PARTITION BY (rn, orig_str, mod_str)
 20              DIMENSION BY (element_no)
 21              MEASURES (start_pos, end_pos, element_count)
 22              RULES ITERATE (2000)
 23              UNTIL (ITERATION_NUMBER+1 = element_count[0])
 24            ( start_pos[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] =
 25                      instr(cv(mod_str), ' ', 1, cv(element_no)) + 1,
 26              end_pos[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] =
 27                      instr(cv(mod_str), ' ', 1, cv(element_no) + 1) )
 28            )
 29         WHERE    element_no != 0
 30    ORDER BY      mod_str , element_no
 31   /

     COUNT
----------
         6
```

Comment: this query work fine but when apply in large amount of data it never show result

Comment: your demo for a string in the sample_data but i already store data in database under column country : record 1="japan singapore japan chinese chinese chinese" record 2="singapore indian malaysia" i want it to count include record1 & record2 @Lalit Kumar B

Comment: @HaziqAzmi I have provided a complete answer in the update. Please mark it as answered, would help others!

Comment: @HaziqAzmi  On the top left of my answer, there is an up arrow to upvote the answer. Below it is a tick mark, just click on it to accept the answer, it would turn green in colour when you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you store that kind of string in a single entry?

If not, try

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T.country FROM Table1 T)
```

If yes, I would write an external program to parse the string and return the result you want.

Like using java.

Create a String set.

I would use JDBC to retrieve the record, and use split to split strings in tokens using ' 'delimiter. For every token, if it is not in the set, add it to the set.

When parse finishes, get the length of the set, which is the value you want.

Comment: yes..the string in a single entry. it is like long string.. "japan singapore japan chinese chinese chinese" is represent as row 1

Comment: It is not easy query i think.. normally people count a certain word in string.  for example: SELECT (LENGTH(QUESTION_ITEM) - LENGTH(REPLACE(QUESTION_ITEM,'EXPLAIN')))/LENGTH('EXPLAIN') FROM CLASSIFY

Comment: please show me the external program to parse the string and return the result

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. Remember, if you could it in `SQL` then do it in `SQL`, if not, do it in `PL/SQL`, if not do it in `JAVA`, if not do it in `C`. In OP's case it could be done in pure `SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Break the string based on the space delimiter

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL))
  FROM T
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(col, ' ')+1
```

For counting DISTINCT words

```
    SELECT col,
COUNT(DISTINCT regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL))
  FROM T
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(col, ' ')+1
GROUP BY col
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91861/6)

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question. You are returning the count of each word, however, OP wants distinct count. Also, no need of `trim` as you only need the count.